# Geting error: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'get_values'. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, int64

I'm kinda new to Data Science and I'm struggling with this project, I would appreciate some help. So, I'm working with some .shp files to get some choropleth-like maps with some other functions, that for my luck are not working because of this error I'm getting.

```
shp_path = '.../Comuna.shp'
sf = shp.Reader(shp_path)

   def read_shapefile(sf):
     fields = [x[0] for x in sf.fields][1:]
     records = sf.records()
     shps = [s.points for s in sf.shapes()]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=fields, data=records)
df = df.assign(coords=shps)

return df

df = read_shapefile(sf)


REGION PROVINCIA COMUNA            NOM_REGION             NOM_PROVIN  \

0      13       131  13114  REGIÓN METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO    SANTIAGO   
1      13       131  13115  REGIÓN METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO    SANTIAGO  

 NOM_COMUNA                                             coords  
0            LAS CONDES  [(-70.47950849099993, -33.36433197899993), (-7...  
1          LO BARNECHEA  [(-70.32034044899996, -33.105245486999934), (-...  

df[df.NOM_COMUNA == 'SANTIAGO']

 REGION PROVINCIA COMUNA                        NOM_REGION NOM_PROVIN  \
25     13       131  13101  REGIÓN METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO   SANTIAGO   

   NOM_COMUNA                                             coords  
25   SANTIAGO  [(-70.66527655199997, -33.42827810699998), (-7...  

def plot_shape(id, s=None):
    """ PLOTS A SINGLE SHAPE """
    plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    shape_ex = sf.shape(id)
    x_lon = np.zeros((len(shape_ex.points),1))
    y_lat = np.zeros((len(shape_ex.points),1))
    for ip in range(len(shape_ex.points)):
        x_lon[ip] = shape_ex.points[ip][0]
        y_lat[ip] = shape_ex.points[ip][1]

    plt.plot(x_lon,y_lat) 
    x0 = np.mean(x_lon)
    y0 = np.mean(y_lat)
    plt.text(x0, y0, s, fontsize=10)
    # use bbox (bounding box) to set plot limits
    plt.xlim(shape_ex.bbox[0],shape_ex.bbox[2])
    return x0, y0

comuna = 'SANTIAGO' 
com_id =df[df.NOM_COMUNA == comuna].index.get_values()[0]
plot_shape(com_id, comuna)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-732395dd9018> in <module>
      1 comuna = 'SANTIAGO'
----> 2 com_id =df[df.NOM_COMUNA == comuna].index.get_values()[0]
      3 plot_shape(com_id, comuna)

AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'get_values'
```

I've built some other functions to get this maps, but I think the root of the problem is this one.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Try `df[df.NOM_COMUNA == comuna].index.values` instead.

You can read more about what Int64Index can/cannot do here in its [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.2/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py#L290-L295).

Comment: Might also be worth linking to the documentation for [pandas.index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) since it's a little easier to digest than the full source code

Comment: I did intend to include Int64Index documentation - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Int64Index.html. The doc wasn't that informative - and going after index itself, considering the types of indexes and understanding how they all get assigned to index property could also cause confusion. So fair enough to the point that we need more documentation. Thanks.

Comment: when I used your answer, I had this error TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. it worked when I changed it to plot_shape(np.array(25), comuna) source: https://github.com/Mjrovai/Python4DS/blob/master/Vector_Mapping_Python/Vectorial_Maps.ipynb

Comment: I had to add the first index like this: com_id = df[df.NOM_COMUNA == comuna].index.values[0]